# Mi GCP dataflow steps are not starting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I have this simple GCP dataflow that reads from pubsub and then prints a log indicating the message arrived.

```
import logging
import os
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./credentials.json"
INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION = "projects/PROJECT_ID/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_NAME"


class FromProtoToJson(beam.DoFn):

    def to_runner_api_parameter(self, unused_context):
        return "beam:transforms:custom_parsing:custom_v0", None

    def process(self, element: bytes, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        logging.info("element arrived")


def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_subscription",
        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>."',
        default=INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION
    )

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "ReadFromPubSub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription, timestamp_attribute=None
            )
            | "FromProtoToJson" >> beam.ParDo(FromProtoToJson())
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

As you can see, it has 2 steps but they are not starting, this dataflow is launched by the command using apache beam 2.41.0:

```
python realtime_pipeline.py --streaming --input_subscription projects/my-project/subscriptions/test-sub --runner DataflowRunner --project my-project --region us-west4 --temp_location gs://my-project-pipeline-bucket --job_name test --max_num_workers 1
```

when I execute that command after all the logs I get: workers have started successfully

No errors are shown neither in deployment nor in dataflow dashboard, however when I go to the logs explorer->logs dashboard I see this error on GCE errors:

```
{
    insertId: "1qzq6lgfm8cwty"
    jsonPayload: {
        localTimestamp: "2022-09-27T10:42:04.7643Z"
        message: "Error updating SSH keys for root: mkdir /root/.ssh: read-only file system."
    }
    logName: "projects/my-project/logs/GCEGuestAgent"
    receiveTimestamp: "2022-09-27T10:42:05.773260545Z"
    resource: {2}
    severity: "ERROR"
    sourceLocation: {3}
    timestamp: "2022-09-27T10:42:04.764323945Z"
}
```

how can I make it work ?, after the message “workers have started successfully” the job seems to be ready but is not being triggered by pubsub…..
thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Are you sure the error from `Cloud logging` is about your `Dataflow` job ?  Many services can run on GCE instance and you can also filter on `Dataflow steps` from Cloud logging. Normally the `Dataflow` UI should also show you errors.

Comment: hi @OlafKock there is no text as image. Thanks

Comment: @MazlumTosun yes they are from the dataflow 100% sure, and no the UI is not showing any errors

Comment: @Juankipedia what's labelled "GCE Error" in the second to last line of your question looks suspiciously like a bunch of characters (aka text) to me

Comment: @OlafKock never mind I changed the image.

Comment: Simple prints are not necessarily shown in the Dataflow log. Replace `print("element arrived")` with `logging.info("element arrived")`, or any other log level (Error is easier to spot ;) ).

Comment: hello @CaptainNabla of course that is NOT the problem since the messages are not being consumed from the topic, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with GCP platform, it is working now :D